# get refreshed database value in every Jpanels

Tags: java, swing

I have three panels for insert, modify and delete users in my `JFrame`, if I insert a value in `insertJpanel` the value is not shown in `modifyPanel` and `deletePanel` but if I close the application and open it again, the new record is there.

How can I have all `JPanels` refreshed together?

Comment: So you want an event to fire when the value in the database changes, that causes the panels to re-populate with the relevant data?

Comment: Java will not automatically select the new values when an insert, update or delete is performed on the database. It is your responsibility to execute the select statement again after any changes occur on the database, and update the GUI accordingly.